# System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms dll in .net 4.8

Tags: c#, cryptography, .net-4.8

I have a console application in visual studio 2015.(.Net FrameWork 4.8)
I've added 3 dlls to this app by NuGet installation like below :

> System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms
> System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding
> System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives

But i have error in this line of c# :

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms;
```

> The type or namespace name 'Algorithms' does not exist in the
> namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?)

What is the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms` is the name of the _assembly_ (the DLL), it's not an actual namespace - all the public algorithm implementations have the immediate namespace `System.Security.Cryptography` (ie. `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256`)

Comment: I've added those dlls because of this error : `The type or namespace name 'AesGcm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: And if you remove `using System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms;` and instead try to reference the `AesGcm` type inside your code, does that work now?

Comment: Still have this error : `The type or namespace name 'AesGcm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` > I only added `using System.Security.Cryptography;`

Comment: See this image : https://i.imgur.com/YyTlkVw.png

Comment: Looks like [netstandard2.1 is the minimum supported version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-6.0#applies-to), .NET 4.8 only implements 2.0, so I'm afraid you won't get `AesGcm` working on 4.8

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen - You are right - Thanks for helping me on this. Put your comments as answer and let me accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to note here:

- The [`AesGcm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-6.0#applies-to) implementation you're looking for is **not** available for .NET Framework 4.8, hence the failure to resolve the desired type name. For a cross-platform implementation it looks like you'll need to upgrade to .NET 5.0
- `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms` is *not* a namespace - it's just the **name of the assembly** (the DLL file on disk) that contains a number of cryptographic algorithm implementations. All public types contained in the corresponding DLL are namespaced to `System.Security.Cryptography`, so the qualified type name for `AesGcm` would have been:

  - `System.Security.Cryptography.AesGcm`